# asp.net: edit resource file which is compiled into a dll

Tags: .net, asp.net, embedded-resource

my asp.net site uses resource files for a referenced project with the user controls in it.

so i have one website project, and one dll project with usercontrols + the resource files.

The website references the dll project.

So far so good.

When i publish, the dll with the usercontrols gets compiled in a dll (what else) but the resource files also get compiled (a separate dll for every language)

Is there a way to edit the resource strings in the dll once deployed?

Comment: In a word - no. Why would you want to edit the resource strings? Are you wanting to edit the strings in the code (ie runtime), or manually as a 'patch'? If the latter, consider not compiling them (ie set them as "Content" in the build action).

Comment: i would like to be able to edit the resource file (which only contains translations for texts) on production in case of a typo, so i don't have to release a whole new build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the whole point is the resource files are fixed and in the dll.  If you want to be able to edit them after deployment then simply deploy your scripts/css or whatever as text files.

Comment: oh, then i think i missed the point :). But what is the difference then between a resourcestring and a hardcoded string?

Comment: An embedded resource is easier to manage and update as it is just a normal file in the VSproject, with css and js files you get all the intelisense as you would any other css or js file. It gets embedded automatically when you compile.  If you want the ability to change the content then simply use a text file that can be edited. Alternativle you can deploy a satellite assembly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb6a8618%28VS.80%29.aspx